how to save turtle drawing as a png?
i am making a paint like app in python using tkinter and turtle. im trying to save the image drawn as a png.
short version of my program :
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial
from turtle import TurtleScreen, RawTurtle, Shape
from PIL import Image

def draw(x, y):
    turtle.ondrag(None)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.penup()
    screen.update()
    turtle.ondrag(draw)

def move(x, y):
    screen.onclick(None)
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    screen.onclick(move)
    screen.update()
    

def set_color(color):
    global pen_color
    pen_color = color
    turtle.pencolor(color)
    screen.update()
    
    # --- add widgets ---

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack(side='right', expand=True, fill='both')

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(side='left', fill='y')

tk.Label(frame, text='COLORS').grid(column=0, row=0)

tk.Button(frame, bg='red', width=10, command=partial(set_color, 'red')).grid(column=0, row=1)
tk.Button(frame, bg='yellow', width=10, command=partial(set_color, 'yellow')).grid(column=0, row=2)
tk.Button(frame, bg='green', width=10, command=partial(set_color, 'green')).grid(column=0, row=3)
tk.Button(frame, bg='blue', width=10, command=partial(set_color, 'blue')).grid(column=0, row=4)
tk.Button(frame, bg='black', width=10, command=partial(set_color, 'black')).grid(column=0, row=5)

def save () :
    drawing = screen.getcanvas()
    drawing.postscript(file='drawing.ps')
    img = Image.open( 'drawing.ps')
    img.save('drawing.png')
    print('...dumping gui window to png')
bsave = tk.Button(
    frame,
    text='save *',
    width=10,
    command=save
)
bsave.grid(column=0, row=6)

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.tracer(False)

pen_color = 'black'

turtle = RawTurtle(screen)
#turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.shape("circle")
polygon = turtle.get_shapepoly()
fixed_color_turtle = Shape("compound")
fixed_color_turtle.addcomponent(polygon, "", "")
screen.register_shape('fixed', fixed_color_turtle)
turtle.shape("fixed")
turtle.penup()
turtle.pensize(5)
turtle.turtlesize(2000,2000)
turtle.ondrag(draw)
screen.onscreenclick(move)
screen.update()
screen.mainloop()

when i run this i get the error : OSError : Unable to locate Ghostscript on paths
i want to save the image without using ghostscript as this program need to run on the school computers and they don't have it.
i also tried this but the x and y values returned are always wrong
def save () :
    x0 = frame.winfo_rootx()
    y0 = frame.winfo_rooty()
    x1 = x0 + frame.winfo_width()
    y1 = y0 + frame.winfo_height()
    ImageGrab.grab().crop((x0, y0, x1, y1)).save('painting.png')


Please see Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? and OSError: Unable to locate Ghostscript on paths

You can use something like this:
from tkinter import *
import turtle

turtle.forward(100)
screen = turtle.getscreen()

screen.getcanvas().postscript(file="FILE_NAME.eps")

That saves it as an eps file, you can view it online or google how to convert it to png.

thanks! but saving as .eps doesn't really help me

The documentation is really hard to follow, but the turtle docs say that screen.getcanvas() returns a Tk (TkInter) canvas, so I think your question is how to save a PNG from a Tk Canvas. As far as I can tell the Tk canvas widget can only save to PostScript (/EPS/PDF), which it apparently does using Ghostscript. You may have other options if you have the Tk Img package but it's not clear to me.
What I thought was an answer doesn't appear to work (let me know if it does) - How to convert canvas content to an image. However: have you tried simply using drawing.postscript(file='drawing.png')? The TkInter.Images document suggests it will write raster images because it hooks into any file or data option.

For my own curiosity, does direct saving as 'drawing.png' not work? It seems like it should be a bug if that's case based on the documentation.
